# Convert GeoTIFF to HDF using gdal

Tags: gdal, hdf

Is it possible to use `gdal_translate` to convert a GeoTIFF to HDF format? According to the format description:

```
$ gdalinfo --formats | grep HDF
  HDF4 -raster,multidimensional raster- (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
  HDF4Image -raster- (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
  HDF5 -raster,multidimensional raster- (rovs): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
  HDF5Image -raster- (rov): HDF5 Dataset
```

only HDF4Image supports writing. But the following command does not terminate and the process **hangs**

```
$ gdal_translate -of HDF4Image tmp.tif out.h4
Input file size is 19263, 12859
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

While an out.h4 file is created data isn't written to it as the file is only 4 bytes in size.

Environment:

Using a conda environment with the following dependencies:

```
gdal                      3.3.0            py37hb0e9ad2_3    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.3.0                h8f005ca_3    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.15               h10796ff_3    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h7c3c948_1111    conda-forge
```

Comment: You are correctly reading the --formats, HDF5 is read only but writing is supported for HDF4, though there may be limitations on coordinate reference system and file dimensions. Read more https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html Do you have the HDF driver installed? I've not used Linux but for Windows the HDF drivers aren't installed by default. When you say the command does not work, what do you mean by doesn't work? that statement stretches between output file not created to smoke coming out of your workstation, please expand a bit on what does happen and any error message you get.

Comment: Added more context. Basically the command does not complete writing to the file.

Comment: Format is odd to me but gdal_translate command hangs for me too with a 3 band source image once the progress bar has reached 100 %. Single band image gets converted fine.

Comment: Do you really need the HDF format? you might try some kind of NetCDF converter instead. Is the TIFF format not good enough?

Comment: @Gery I'm trying to test some scripts on multiple raster formats. So instead of downloading files, I thought I would use `gdal_translate` to convert a tiff I had to different formats. That's when I stumbled across this error.